# I think the disclaimer does not attract enough attention

Tags: discussion

Will the disclaimer be effective, if it's not attracting attention?

For me, it does not.

I think the disclaimer should always attract notice, at least for those coming to the site at the first time. Maybe make it a different color? (Red is good)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you.

I think the location - while fine and appropriate - might lend it to "bleed" into the announcements below it, which are easy to overlook.

The font size, layout, different color of the words "educational purposes only", and the link are all excellent in my opinion.

I admit to being a bit on the slightly paranoid side, but my preference would be to have it in a ["black box"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxed_warning), something that was started on prescription medication package inserts when serious or life-threatening adverse effects became known about a drug.

A two (or three?) pixel border (assuming that the announcements have a one pixel border) of black or red would be my suggestion.

Tim provided this comparison: [1, 2, and 3 pixel borders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iG4p3.jpg).

Edited to add: I like the 3 px border (thank you, Tim!) best.

Comment: Yeah, I think a black, wide border of the box is better. It draws enough attention but not so bright so you can't be distracted by it.

Comment: This is 1px, 2px and 3px: http://imgur.com/a/PLCt5

Comment: @Tim - Thank you!

Comment: I would go for 1 or 2 - and if it's black it will look different to the announcements box anyway.

Comment: so, any consensus here?